# jQuery mobile app always scrolls if screen is shorter than some size

Tags: jquery-mobile

The content on my screen is definitely able to fit into the given screen size, yet the app still shows scrollbars if the screen is shorter than a certain height.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXvHG/1) shows the issue, if you shrink the `result` pane to a certain height.

**What I've tried:**

Adding `overflow-y:hidden' to the body fixes this issue, but I want to be able to scroll in the y-direction if needed, just not when it's not needed.

How can I stop this scrolling when unnecessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason ended up being because of a rule in the jQueryMobile.css:

```
.ui-page, bla, bla{
    min-height: 420px;
}
```

changing that to a smaller number that matches what I needed fixed the issue.